# What are the usual higher-order primitives on lists in functional programming? (map, fold, and?)

Tags: functional-programming

What do you usually do with a list in purely functional programming?

Obviously we have `map f [x0; x1; x2]` which produces `[f x0; f x1; f x2]` and `fold f acc [x0; x1; x2]` which produces `f (f (f acc x0) x1) x2)`.

For `map`, no information is transmitted between calls to `f`; for `fold`, all the information produced by `f` is re-injected in the next call through the accumulator `acc`.

I've also seen things like `flatmap` that concatenates the lists produced by `map f` when `f` returns a list and `for_all` that applies a predicate to all elements of the lists, but these are just special cases of `map` and `fold`.

I can think about something intermediate that would produce a list but also keep an accumulator during iteration (OCaml syntax):

```
let rec map_acc ~f acc = function
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> let (y, acc) = f x acc in y::(map_acc ~f acc xs)
```

Questions:

- is `map_acc` a usual concept in functional programming?
- if yes, what's its canonical name?
- is it implemented in standard libraries?
- **what are the other usual higher-order functions?**

Notes:

Here is an example where `map_acc` is used to produce running sums:

```
let sums xs = map_acc ~f:(fun x sum -> let sum = sum + x in (sum, sum)) 0 xs
```

And `sums [3; 5; 6; 9]` produces `[3; 8; 14; 23]`. Granted `sums` can be implemented using `fold` and a well-tailored accumulator, but it is simpler with `mac_acc`.

Comment: Regarding your last comment about `sums`, technically *everything* could be implemented as `fold`, but it would get pretty ugly. Also, I'm surprised `filter` didn't show up on your list already.

Comment: It's not a usual concept in functionnal programming (for me of course).

Answer (score 2):

`map_acc` looks like a slightly more general `scan_left`:

```
let scan_left f init list =
  let _, xs = List.fold_left
      (fun (acc, coll) elt ->
         let acc' = f acc elt in acc', acc'::coll)
      (init, []) list in
  List.rev xs

scan_left (+) 0 [3; 5; 6; 9] => [3; 8; 14; 23]
```

This function and variants appear under various names in the standard libraries of a few functional languages, although not OCaml.

None of these functions really deserve being called primitives.